# Not a function error, Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

Im messing around with Polymer a little bit and I'm trying to create a simple get request to retrieve my Github information. I'm retrieving the error `Polymer.httpRequest is not a function`. When clearly it is.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'custom-element',
    properties: {
        name: ''
    },
    httpRequest: function(type, url){
        var getRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data = getRequest.responseText;
        getRequest.open(type, url, true);
        getRequest.send();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
});

Polymer.httpRequest('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3');
```

Any ideas why it's returning this error? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: After you get rid of the Polymer error, You can not return from an asynchronous method. And you are reading the responseText BEFORE you make the Ajax call.

Comment: You do not call the method with Polymer. You call it with the element it references.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer does not have the httpRequest method that you created. Instead, that method is created for the "custom-element".

You can access the method on the new element shown below:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="custom-element">
<template></template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'custom-element',
     properties: {
     name: ''
    },
    ready: function () {
      this.httpRequest('GET', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
    },
    httpRequest: function(type, url){
      var getRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var data = getRequest.responseText;
      getRequest.open(type, url, true);
      getRequest.send();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```